How to limit motor current during fast deceleration and regenerative load?
For a voltage source inverter which is used to drive a PMSM motor (using field oriented control), when we instruct the motor to reduce speed quickly (fast deceleration,) we notice that the DC bus raises as the regenerative energy is fed back to the DC bus capacitors.
To keep the DC bus voltage regulated, we have implemented a dynamic brake which switches and modulates a brake switch similar to what is said here:
Inverter DC link voltage rises when motor decelerates

The problem we are facing is that during regenerative torque, we notice that the motor current increases, so much so that in some cases it trips the comparator which monitors for overcurrent situations.
I have a few unclear doubts regarding what is happening in this situation:

If there is no load connected, if the motor is requested to decelerate quickly, at that point what should ideally happen to the motor currents, should they increase in amplitude?

When there is a constant regenerative torque applied as a load, the dynamic brake kicks in, which brings down the DC bus voltage, but the motor currents are now very choppy and have a lot of oscillations (very poor current regulation.)
Momentarily when the brake is turned on (during on-time of the brake PWM,) the DC bus drops and the motor phase current raises. Again when the DC bus raises (now the motor phase current drops) the brake switches on again and this process continues until the regenerative load is not present anymore.
Sometimes when there a high regenerative load, this current oscillation will be so much that it trips the over current comparator.
Is there any way to improve the current regulation, in this situation?

Combining points 1 and 2, if there is such a situation where there is a request to lower speed quickly (fast decelerations) and a high regenerative load present simultaneously, every time this would trip the over current comparator, again how do we limit current in this situation?
Please note that during regenerative load, always there is no current drawn from the battery.


We tried adding a limit to the quadrature axis current (Iq reference,) but during regeneration, if this limit is hit, then the motor speed can no longer be controlled and speed of the motor would start to increase.
UPDATE:
Oscilloscope waveforms:
C1 is the DC bus voltage
C2 is the Brake Switch current
C3 is the Motor phase current.
C4 is DC bus current from the input
Wholistic view of the test:
[![Wholistic view][2]][2]
Brake switch DC bus regulation:
The bus is regulated at 300v.
[![DC bus regulation][3]][3]
Some Context to understand the setup:

Motor rotation direction is 'negative'.
So an opposing torque means a 'negative quadrature current reference' and a regenerative torque means a 'positive quadrature current reference'
Using another  Motor , We give an 'Opposing Load torque' and slowly
transition into giving 'regenerative load torque'.
We also try to reduce the speed quickly(fast deceleration) to try and
capture any abnormalities during sudden deceleration.
The quadrature axis current is capped to 20% effort in
software.(Direct axis current is always zero).
In the Motor inverter hardware, the OC Comparator threshold is
hardwired at 80%.

The following plots show the current reference commanded during the given variable load profile as mentioned above. The current reference slowly moves from negative to positive as the load torque changes from an opposing torque to a regenerative torque.

The following plot shows the speed and quadrature current together:

Notice that the moment speed is commanded to suddenly reduce(3250 RPM to 1500 RPM),
the quadrature current hits the capped limit and the speed does reduce, more importantly it does reduce at the commanded deceleration rate, but at the expense of a sudden motor current spike.
Question here: Is this spike a normal behavior due to a very high deceleration rate demanded?


Now how do we control this current spike?
The current controller can limit the quadrature current reference, is there anything else that can be done? or anyother controlling action
that needs to be done.?
In case of an opposing torque, the amplitude of the motor current strictly adheres to the limit, incase more opposing torque is given by the load, which breaches the current limit set, the speed slowly starts to reduce and eventually comes to a stop as the opposing torque is increased. (motor stall, basically),
But at any point in time the absolute motor current amplitude does not cross the limit.
But doesn't seem to be the case during regeneration.

I am not an expert in this field, but I want to make sure I understand the question: you want to decelerate fast, and this generates currents that the system is unable to handle. Is this the case? In case, have you considered a mechanical brake? You have to dissipate the energy somehow, and if you wanna do it fast, you will need something able to handle the peak power.

Does the brake PWM try to regulate to some particular voltage? Hysteresis control? Can you post brake PWM, DC bus voltage and motor current oscillogram?

@winny Yes, The brake chopper operates from 300v onwards. Nominal DC bus voltage is 250v. Its just a simple lookup table in software. I will try to post some waveforms

@VladimirCravero Yes mechanical brake is an option, but we first want to squeeze out the maximum braking from the switch before having to use a mechanical brake.


How to limit motor current during fast deceleration and regenerative load?

The same way you limit the current during acceleration. The current control loop has this job. It needs to observe the combined capacity of the motor and the drive system, and keep the current limited - whether it is a positive or negative current. Braking is not a special case!

during the regenerative torque […] motor current increases

You’re talking about it as if the motor was doing things of its own volition. You make the servo drive and you control the current. If it is too high, your control scheme is at fault, not braking or the motor or anything else.
After all, the current control loop is the innermost loop in your controller. It is up to that loop to limit motor current no matter if the torque is positive or negative.
The comparator you speak of is there only to protect against control system faults that cause the current control loop to exceed the motor ratings. This should never happen unless there is a fault in the drive. It can be a transient fault, but still - it should never normally happen.
So, it seems to me that the current control loop in your servo does not limit the current according to the ratings of the motor. As simple as that.
The current control loop has to limit the absolute value of the current - so both negative and positive current. It looks like your current control loop doesn’t do that. Perhaps it’s misconfigured, or poorly implemented.
In short: your problem has nothing to do with braking but everything to do with the drive not doing perhaps the most basic part of its job - that of controlling the motor current.
The braking has just exposed the problem and you’re lucky it happened before the devices got out into the field. Now you have a chance to properly fix it and to figure out any procedural mistakes that led to this bug (no matter if it is a software bug, FPGA HDL bug, circuit bug, etc).
And don’t forget that just because you command a deceleration doesn’t mean that the servo and the motor have the capacity to actually decelerate at that rate. Usually in a servo drive you can command arbitrarily high acceleration or deceleration but the drive will limit the instantaneous torque to what the electronics, cabling, power source and the motor can actually handle.

Yes, i am aware that there is something not right and debugging the system. But i am able to properly control current during opposing torque very well, but seem to be facing current oscillations during regen. I will try to post some data , hopefully to beter understand my problems.

All opposing torque is regeneration... the energy has to go somewhere, after all.
